# installing "sasl" in python

Tags: python, hive, sasl

When trying to install sasl in python to connect with Hive, it gives an error. Please advise how to treat it?
pip install sasl

> ```
>     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>
>   Using cached sasl-0.3.1.tar.gz (44 kB)
> Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\dpgorbunov\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sasl) (1.15.0)
> Building wheels for collected packages: sasl
>   Building wheel for sasl (setup.py): started
>   Building wheel for sasl (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
>   Running setup.py clean for sasl
> Failed to build sasl
> Installing collected packages: sasl
>     Running setup.py install for sasl: started
>     Running setup.py install for sasl: finished with status 'error'
>
>    command: 'C:\Users\DPGorbunov\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> ```
>
> '"'"'C:\Users\DPGorbunov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1wo6vhy\sasl_93edfeed199a468f9957192525095be9\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\DPGorbunov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1wo6vhy\sasl_93edfeed199a468f9957192525095be9\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d
> 'C:\Users\DPGorbunov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-96bq5ujy'
> cwd: C:\Users\DPGorbunov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1wo6vhy\sasl_93edfeed199a468f9957192525095be9
> Complete output (27 lines):
> running bdist_wheel
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sasl
> copying sasl_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sasl
> running egg_info
> writing sasl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
> writing dependency_links to sasl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
> writing requirements to sasl.egg-info\requires.txt
> writing top-level names to sasl.egg-info\top_level.txt
> reading manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
> writing manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> copying sasl\saslwrapper.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sasl
> copying sasl\saslwrapper.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sasl
> copying sasl\saslwrapper.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sasl
> running build_ext
> building 'sasl.saslwrapper' extension
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\sasl
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isasl
> -IC:\Users\DPGorbunov\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\DPGorbunov\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsasl/saslwrapper.cpp
> /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\sasl/saslwrapper.obj
> saslwrapper.cpp
> C:\Users\DPGorbunov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1wo6vhy\sasl_93edfeed199a468f9957192525095be9\sasl\saslwrapper.h(22):
> fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: sasl/sasl.h: No
> such file or directory,
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'
> failed with exit status 2
> ----------------------------------------
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for sasl
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'C:\Users\DPGorbunov\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\Users\DPGorbunov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1wo6vhy\sasl_93edfeed199a468f9957192525095be9\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\DPGorbunov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1wo6vhy\sasl_93edfeed199a468f9957192525095be9\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\DPGorbunov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hb8t66nd\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\DPGorbunov\Anaconda3\Include\sasl'
> cwd: C:\Users\DPGorbunov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1wo6vhy\sasl_93edfeed199a468f9957192525095be9
> Complete output (27 lines):
> running install
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sasl
> copying sasl_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sasl
> running egg_info
> writing sasl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
> writing dependency_links to sasl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
> writing requirements to sasl.egg-info\requires.txt
> writing top-level names to sasl.egg-info\top_level.txt
> reading manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
> writing manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> copying sasl\saslwrapper.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sasl
> copying sasl\saslwrapper.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sasl
> copying sasl\saslwrapper.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sasl
> running build_ext
> building 'sasl.saslwrapper' extension
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\sasl
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isasl
> -IC:\Users\DPGorbunov\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\DPGorbunov\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsasl/saslwrapper.cpp
> /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\sasl/saslwrapper.obj
> saslwrapper.cpp
> C:\Users\DPGorbunov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1wo6vhy\sasl_93edfeed199a468f9957192525095be9\sasl\saslwrapper.h(22):
> fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: sasl/sasl.h: No
> such file or directory,
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'
> failed with exit status 2
> ----------------------------------------
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\DPGorbunov\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys,
> setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\Users\DPGorbunov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1wo6vhy\sasl_93edfeed199a468f9957192525095be9\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\DPGorbunov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1wo6vhy\sasl_93edfeed199a468f9957192525095be9\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\DPGorbunov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hb8t66nd\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\DPGorbunov\Anaconda3\Include\sasl' Check the logs for full
> command output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this if your using ubuntu

> apt-get install libsasl2-dev libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit

Answer (score 1):

Download the compiled library sasl.whl for your python version.

it could be from https://www.wheelodex.org/projects/sasl/

- import the .whl file to the server,
- open a terminal on the server and navigate to the place where you imported the file
- run this command for the sasl.whl be sure to type exactly the file name: pip install sasl_xxxx.whl